# Xerces setTextContent method strips new lines / carriage returns. How to prevent?

Tags: java, xml, whitespace, xerces

I'm using Xerces (Java) to generate XML documents. I have a large block of text (including carriage returns and new lines) that I would like to replicate exactly in my XML document as the text content of an element. For example:

```
<element>This is some text
here is some more
that's all folks</element>
```

However, whenever I try use:

```
element.setTextContent(myBlockOfText)
```

All the new lines are replaced with single space characters.

How can I keep the new lines within this block of text using Xerces? (Tried CDATA, but it's really only for quoting XML (left angle brackets etc) within XML itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have control of the document?  If so, you might try the xml:space attribute.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space and http://codeidol.com/java/java-xml-for-web/Generating-and-Serializing-XML-Documents/Handling-Whitespace/

Comment: I tried adding 'xml:space' as an attribute to the root element, however it is still condensing line breaks etc. Argh...

Comment: I believe you need to declare xml:space in a DTD for it to work.

Comment: Do you want to post a short "solution" here?

Comment: I haven't got the code to hand today (different job), will do so when I can.