# create basic line breaks with an Xpath Expression from Java to XML file

Tags: java, xml, xpath, carriage-return

Throghout learning how to program Stack Overflow has provided a wealth of information, and a staple of learning how to figure out different things. However for this problem, after searching for a few days and coming up empty handed I've decided to create my first post.

The problem, creating a mulit line value in an XML file from a java string using Xpath's Node.setTextContent. Its writing to a value tag in the XML file that Xpath reports as an element node. Now when writing the string value to the node, it does indeed write the string value to the node, however its just one long string value, as the setTextContent method according to the API does not parse any thing in the string and just writes the text. An example of the data I'm trying to write is:(edited 2-16, just noticed the format option wasn't showing the main post) formated like below with the street, city state and phone broken down like the info below (with out the spaces in between the lines) to match the format as listed in the first the xml code example.

496 Vivid Ave.

Some City, State, 11111

111-222-3333

When the java string is wrote to xml file its entered as:
496 Vivid Ave. Some City, State, 11111 111-222-3333

An example of the node created from the parent program (not my java app) is :

```
<field sid="ADDRESS">
     <itemlocation>
        <ae>
           <ae>absolute</ae>
           <ae>33</ae>
           <ae>168</ae>
        </ae>
     </itemlocation>
     <value>496 Vivid Ave.
Some City, State, 11111
111-222-3333</value>
     <borderwidth>0</borderwidth>
     <fontinfo>
        <ae>Times New Roman</ae>
        <ae>10</ae>
        <ae>plain</ae>
     </fontinfo>
     <scrollhoriz>wordwrap</scrollhoriz>
     <scrollvert>fixed</scrollvert>
     <format>
        <ae>string</ae>
        <ae>optional</ae>
     </format>
     <acclabel>6.  leave address.
enter street, city, state, zip code and phone number.
</acclabel>
     <size>
        <ae>35</ae>
        <ae>3</ae>
     </size>
     <previous>FIELD5</previous>
     <next>ORDINARY</next>
  </field>
```

When i run my app the ouput of raw xml data looks like this:

```
<field sid="ADDRESS">
     <itemlocation>
        <ae>
           <ae>absolute</ae>
           <ae>33</ae>
           <ae>168</ae>
        </ae>
     </itemlocation>
     <value>496 Vivid Ave. Some City, State, 11111 111-222-3333</value>
     <borderwidth>0</borderwidth>
     <fontinfo>
        <ae>Times New Roman</ae>
        <ae>10</ae>
        <ae>plain</ae>
     </fontinfo>
     <scrollhoriz>wordwrap</scrollhoriz>
     <scrollvert>fixed</scrollvert>
     <format>
        <ae>string</ae>
        <ae>optional</ae>
     </format>
     <acclabel>6.  leave address.
enter street, city, state, zip code and phone number.
</acclabel>
     <size>
        <ae>35</ae>
        <ae>3</ae>
     </size>
     <previous>FIELD5</previous>
     <next>ORDINARY</next>
  </field>
```

I have tried to manually enter the escaped characters for line feed and carriage return in the string , and all it does is prting the code values, not the value.

As the parent program reads my Java code it does not break down the address and phone number on separate lines.

The java i'm using looks like:

```
public void setFieldValue(String sid, String value){
    Node resultNode = null;
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    try{

        resultNode = (Node)xPath.evaluate(makeFieldString(sid), doc,XPathConstants.NODE);

    }catch(XPathExpressionException xpee){System.out.println(xpee + "Could not retrive node");}
     if (resultNode != null){

        resultNode.setTextContent(value);

    }
    else System.out.println("Epic fail");

    }

public String makeFieldString(String sid){
    String output=null;
    if (sid.equals("POPUP2")){
        output="//popup[@sid='" + sid + "']/value";
    }

    else{
       output=  "//field[@sid='" + sid + "']/value";
    }
    return output;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to get the Java string to include line breaks that the setTextContent will recognize I would appreaciate it. I have tossed the idea around of trying to use text Normalize and white space data, but not really sure how to implement it, and  not sure if those methods would be striped out from the setTextContent method anyway.

Thanks for any help! I hope I was clear enough in my question to not get flamed!

Comment: "and all it does is prting the code values, not the value." can you give an example?

Comment: In the parent program, the address is read just as its listed in the value elements listed above. So the parent program reads the address into the address box as 496 Vivid Ave. Some City, State, 11111 111-222-3333 in one line, and word wraps it as it sees fit, rather then when created in the parent program, in the first set of 
XML code, where the addy/phone numbers are formated just like in the XML code... aka, where there is a return, in the top xml example, the parent program reads the break, and displays exactly like the XML code.. does that make sense?

Comment: yes, I was just wondering what you mean by "prting the code values" How does this look like?

Comment: I"m not sure how to be more concise :( The app i'm owrking on is to automate some of the form creations we do at work, so in the parent program when you type in the street addy and hit the return key, it moves down a line, then you type in the city, state zip, then hit the return key, and type the phone number in. when the parent program saves the xml file, its entered into the value element however you type in the box, which is the first set of xml code above, notice the formatting where there are lines have line breaks after each set.

Comment: When using my app, and Xpath, setting the nodes text value to save the data, it is only pulled from a single string. That string is pulled from a database, and being a single string it stores the address in a single line in the xml value element, as per the example in the second set of xml code. When that xml file is opened in the parent program, it renders the address value just as its listed in that value element, so it renders the address with outline breaks, as single continous value. And displays it as a single value, with out the line break formatting.

Comment: might be a similar problem as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551405/xerces-settextcontent-method-strips-new-lines-carriage-returns-how-to-prevent

Comment: yes I've looked at that one before posting myself, however in that thread, you need to have access to the DTD, and the original poster didn't follow up on how he got it to work, but in my case, I don't think it will work, as I don't have access to the DTD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an xpather cheetsheet at http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html which showed the special characters in regular expressions, whereas Xpath would not insert the unicoode value of a line break, it did recognize \n for new line and now the address block is formatted correctly.